# What pitch of voice is more versatile for editing and to use as many kinds of voice?

Tags: pitch

I would like to find a pitch of voice that can be edited to sound as many different kinds of voice, a child, a men, a women, a robot, etc.

For instance, if I record a child's voice and a man with a very deep voice, which is less likely to lose quality when I edit it to change its pitch, or to apply some other sound effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use almost any voice today with re-pitching that consider formant.

But a "generic voice" could be a low tenor or high baritone voice.

More on voice types:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_type